# Error message on Safari browser - CSS font import issues

Tags: css, debugging, safari, font-face, font-family

I'm making a call on Stackoverflow for something really wired that happen to me, and after many researches I didn't find a solution for this problem.

Currently working for an e-learning platform, I would like to test some CSS3 animations on the different browsers. Unfortunately, when I'm opening the website *on Safari*, I've got an error message : **A problem repeatedly occurred with "mywebsite.com"**.

The strange thing is that on my colleagues computers, there is no error message. So of course before asking my question here, I've searching for some issues on the web : *Clear Caches & and all history ; unable/disable browser plugins ; uninstall/install Java ; Reset network on my mac with the terminal* ... And after more than half day, I find the beginning of the answer. **The real problem is** that the font files (.ttf, .eot, .woff ...) create a big failed ! When I removed the *@fontface* and the *font-family* calls in the css file, the error message disappear, and unfortunatly, the font that I want disappear too ...

So wonder how I can do to keep my font and remove this error message. Is it a programming issue ? Or maybe is it linked to my personal computer settings* ? (*I've got a Macbook pro 15" with El Capitan 10.11 OS)

Thank you in advance for the help that you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried validating your code (markup & styles) to look for any potential issues? Some browsers will try to be more forgiving and assume what you meant while other will be more literal and brake if something is off.

Comment: On the W3C website you mean ? I do, and there no critical problems. Just "alt" atribute who are missing, and some <a> links not use properly, but usefull for js functions

Comment: I'm gonna check this ;) Come to you soon

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried validating your code (markup & styles) to look for any potential issues?  *Lee Wise*

I have checked the errors and it seems that there is a conflict between Bootstrap and my style. It's gonna be difficult to give a precise response, but to be short and clear : **I removed a lot of useless css and I created a new .css file with the code that I need, and the good way to import font (@import with my .ttf)**.

And Now I can see ;)